# jdbc query using select with all column title instead of using '*' in oracle table join

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to use join method with two table; one is Pokemon and another one is Trainer.

I made xml file related to Oracle and working in JDBC environment
It was successfully working to see the result in console if I used the quote in xml file:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM   POKEMON p
     , TRAINER t 
WHERE p.TRNO = t.TRNO 
AND t.TRID = ?
```

but how i wanted to write instead of * in xml is:

```
SELECT  PKNO
              , p.PKNAME
              , p.PKTYPE
              , p.PKCLASS
              , p.PKHEIGHT
              , p.PKWEIGHT
              , p.PKDETAIL
              , t.TRNO (or p.TRNO since TRNO in POKEMON is referenced to TRNO in TRAINER table)
FROM POKEMON p, TRAINER t 
WHERE p.TRNO = t.TRNO 
AND t.TRID = 'user01';
```

Above those two quote without '*' are working finely in Oracle Developer but I want them to be used in xml file and i want to see them working in Eclipse.

Unfortunately the exception has been shown too and the result is not in English but I'm sure it must be 'Ambiguous Name Column' something like this in English. I don't know why it is not shown in English even though I'm using Eclipse in English. Please let me know if there's any information I should add for your convenience since I'm not still familir with SOF. Thank you!!

Code for the query :

```
public ArrayList<Pokemon> displayMyPokemon(Connection conn, String userId) {
        ArrayList<Pokemon> list = new ArrayList<Pokemon>();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        String sql = prop.getProperty("displayMyPokemon");

        try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, userId);
            rset = pstmt.executeQuery();

            while (rset.next()) {

                Trainer t = new Trainer();
                t.setTrNo(rset.getInt("TRNO"));
                t.setTrId(rset.getString("TRID"));
                t.setTrPwd(rset.getString("TRPWD"));
                t.setTrName(rset.getString("TRNAME"));

                Pokemon p = new Pokemon(rset.getInt("PKNO"), rset.getString("PKNAME"), rset.getString("PKTYPE"),
                        rset.getString("PKCLASS"), rset.getDouble("PKHEIGHT"), rset.getDouble("PKWEIGHT"),
                        rset.getString("PKDETAIL"), rset.getInt("TRNO"));

                list.add(p);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(rset);
            close(pstmt);

        }

        return list;
    }
```

Table Pokemon

```
PKNO    NUMBER  No
PKNAME  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No
PKTYPE  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No
PKCLASS VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No
PKHEIGHT    NUMBER  Yes
PKWEIGHT    NUMBER  Yes
PKDETAIL    VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)  Yes
TRNO    NUMBER  Yes
```

Table Trainer

```
TRNO    NUMBER  Yes
TRID    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No
TRPWD   VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No
TRNAME  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No
```

TRNO in Pokemon is references the one in Trainer

Comment: do not post images of text. nobody can run that.   Go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and create the tables, data, etc so someone can test it

Comment: I think you're missing some alias, so PKNO or TRNO, can you post how you do the query(code/framework/table definition)?

Comment: @WoAiNii Hello I just uploaded some more information about How I wrote the code in Eclipse and Oracle DB. Please let me know if there's anything I need to upload for your convenience. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see TRID, TRPWD, TRPWD and TRNAME in the above query, can you post sql error code? If it's [ORA-00918](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00918_column_ambiguously_defined.htm) check and add an alias where needed. If you post all the related code we can point out the exact line with the problem.